# How to Share Custom Resource Property Values

Tags: chef-infra

I just started writing custom resources following the [new pattern](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources.html) introduced in Chef 12.5.

I'd like to share property values between resources. For example, there may be a resource that installs an application, and then another resource to add features to that app, and is dependent on the install location.

```
app 'myApp' do
    install_path '/usr/local'
    action       :install
end

app_feature 'newFeature' do
    app     'myApp'
    action  :install
end
```

The `app_feature` resource is dependent on the `install_path` of the `app` resource. How do I refer to `install_path` within the `app_feature` code?

I've seen something like this done in the [Poise Python cookbook](https://github.com/poise/poise-python/#python_execute), but being new to resource development I haven't been able to translate it to my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a feature of Poise called "subresources" where there is a parent/child relationship between two resources (a container and child). The child can access the parent's data via an accessor method. Unfortunately, like most of Poise, I haven't actually documented any of this very well :-(

You might want to check out the application cookbook, as it has a framework for implementing stuff like this relatively easily.